# Unwanted space in path for `\addbibresource`

Tags: biblatex, catcodes

I wanted to store a part of a path to a bib-file in a command. But if I run this example (neither the bib-file nor the bib-entry is needed to see the problem) I get an unwanted space in the path:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\newcommand\pathtosrc{test/}
\addbibresource{\pathtosrc contact.bib}
%\edef\bibpath{\pathtosrc contact.bib}
%\addbibresource{\bibpath}
\begin{document}
\cite{a}
\end{document}
```

biber gives an error message which shows that there a space in the path after test/:

```
 ERROR - Cannot find 'test/ contact.bib'
```

## Questions

- Is this a bug or a feature?
- How could one suppress the space apart the `\edef` variant?

Comment: did you try `\addbibresource{{\pathtosrc}contact.bib}`?

Comment: @musicman This gives the path `{test/}contact.bib`, and biber doesn't find the bib.

Comment: I noticed this as well, used `\jobname-bib.bib` since then. Doesn't solve the problem at hand tough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\addbibresource` does `\begingroup\blx@hook@fileverb` which does

```
\let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode`\\=\z@\catcode`\{=\@ne\catcode`\}=\tw@
```

before grabbing the real argument, with the consequence that spaces in the argument are absorbed with category code 12, so they aren't ignored after control sequences.

I'd say to try

```
\appto\blx@hook@fileverb{\catcode`\ =10 }
```

but I don't know the consequences with file name interpretations, when the names contain spaces.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\appto\blx@hook@fileverb{\catcode`\ =10 }
\makeatother
\newcommand\pathtosrc{Tesi classica/}
\addbibresource{\pathtosrc Bibliografia.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{a}
\end{document}
```

I have a `Tesi classica` directory in my working directory. Here's the terminal output when running Biber:

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'addbibspace.blg'
INFO - Reading 'addbibspace.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Tesi classica/Bibliografia.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Tesi classica/Bibliografia.bib'
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'a' (section 0)
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'addbibspace.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
INFO - Output to addbibspace.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

Thus the suggested path seems to work.

Without the patch, a strategy such as

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definebiberpath}[2]{%
   \newcommand{#1}{#2\@gobble}%
}
\makeatother

\definebiberpath{\pathtosrc}{Tesi classica/}
```

will work.

Comment: I wouldn't care about file names with spaces but the core of my question is how one can I separate my command from the following text if spaces can have catcode 12? My best ideas currently are `\addbibresource{\pathtosrc\@gobble.contact.bib}` and `\newcommand\pathtosrc[1]{test/}` with the use `\pathtoscr!`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried applying the suggested patch to `\blx@hook@fileverb` and even with a directory with a space in its name it works. See the example.